# JSLink not displaying

Tags: 2013, jslink

This is my second display template, which is mostly a copy of the first one. All of the configurations are the same, but for some reason it's not firing when the page is loaded.

here is the configuration within the masterpage gallery

[image]

within the webpart configuration, this is the url that I'm using

```
 ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/block_release_form.js
```

here is the code

```
(function () {
var blockReleaseFormFieldCtx = {};

// Define template variable     
blockReleaseFormFieldCtx.Templates = {};


// Define your required fields and functions to call in each case.
blockReleaseFormFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "BCD2": {
        "View": BlockReleaseFormViewTemplate
    },

};

// Register the template override with SP2013 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(blockReleaseFormFieldCtx));
})();

function BlockReleaseFormViewTemplate(ctx) {
var _blockCreatedDate = ctx.CurrentItem.BCD2;
var _approvedHours = ctx.CurrentItem.ApprovedHours;

// View must contain the columns used
//if(_blockCreatedDate == 'undefined' || _approvedHours == 'undefined'){
//  return '';
//}

if (_blockCreatedDate >= "21" )
{
    return "<div style='background-color: #B5BBFF; width: 100%; display: block; border: 2px solid #2500DE; padding-left: 2px;'></div>";
    //return alert("We are 21");
}
else if (_blockCreatedDate <= '21')
{
    return "<div style='background-color: #FFB5B5; width: 100%; display: block; border: 2px solid #DE0000; padding-left: 2px;'></div>";
}    
}
```

Comment: What are you attaching the display template code to?  And is it on the same object that you attached your first display template to?

Comment: Attaching this to the list view (allitems.aspx). This is a different site collection/list from the first display template.

Comment: Did you debug? Is there breakpoint hitting on it? Try publishing the file and check.

Comment: what would be the best way to debug? I'm looking at the source tab in Chrome dev tools, and I'm not seeing the script file

Comment: If you're not seeing the script file, it may not be loading.  Is the site collection this is supposed to be used for the root site of the web application?  (i.e. the site collection URL is http: //my.server.name/)  I have never set up a display template with a target scope as broad as `/`.  Maybe try specifying something more specific for the target scope, like `/sites/sitecollectionName`?  (Or whatever the URL is to this particular site collection.)